# How to use v-select but not repeat itself while using v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-select

I have array of json in `groupData`, how to pass the data to `v-select`

I know what I am doing is wrong by using v-for inside v-select, but I am not sure how to pass data:

```
<v-select multiple
  v-for="group in groupsData"
  :value.sync="selected"
  :options="[{label: group.group_name, value: group.id}]">
</v-select>
```

Plugin URL: https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/

This is how it's done with vue.js without `v-select` plugin and this works:

```
<select v-model="selected" multiple>
  <option v-for="group in groupsData" v-bind:value="group.group_id">{{group.group_name}}</option>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically I use a computed property.

```
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    groupsData: groups,
    selected:[]
  },
  computed:{
    selectOptions(){
      return this.groupsData.map(g => ({label: g.group_name, value: g.id}))
    }
  }
})
```

And in your template

```
<v-select multiple
          :value.sync="selected"
          :options="selectOptions">
</v-select>
```

Working [example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/mwjZVE?editors=1010).

Answer (score 1):

`v-for` repeats the entire element, which is not what you want.

Instead, you want to transform your array into the `options` parameter.

`:` expressions accept arbitrary Javascript code, so you can do that exactly as you would in Javascript:

```
:options="groupsData.map(g => ({label: g.name, value: g.id}))"
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Your code make sense but I could not make it work. I have updated my answer, in case for further reference. Currently I am getting errors like: `[Vue warn]: Error in getter for watcher "filteredOptions": (found in <VSelect>)`